# Calling sed within perl with a variable

Tags: perl, sed

I would like to inplace edit ssd_config file where i need to replace the #Port  to a custom port.

### Before:

```
#Port <portnum>

 ex: #Port 22
```

### After:

```
Port <customport>

ex: Port 2022
```

Here the custom port is coming in a variable $port.

I tried the below script but does nothing.

```
my $prt = "Port 2022";
my $cmd = "sed -i \'s/#Port [0-9]\+/$prt/g\' sshd_config";
system($cmd);
```

Tried even with tick operator.

```
`sed -i \"s/#Port [0-9]\+/\$prt/g\" sshd_config`;
```

Comment: Please don't use `system($cmd)` but use `system(@cmd)` instead, i.e. give command and argument not together as a string but as separate parameters to skip invoking a shell with all the escaping trouble. Also, why depend on sed if the same task could be  done in perl directly?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich what is the shortest way to achive this in perl directly, i mean inplace editing a config file and change a string in it when a pattern matches ?

Comment: `perl -pi  -e "s/#Port [0-9]\+/$prt/g" sshd_config`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything sed can do, Perl can do.

If this is your entire Perl program:

```
my $prt = "Port 2022";
my $cmd = "sed -i \'s/#Port [0-9]\+/$prt/g\' sshd_config";
system($cmd);
```

Then you can do it all in Perl itself from the command line.

```
perl -i -p -e's/#Port [0-9]+/Port 2022/g' sshd_config
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest to do all that in Perl, once you are running a Perl program.  That way one doesn't have to run external programs, not to mention the benefits of not having to mess with all the quoting and escaping if you actually need a shell (not in the shown example though).

Then we need a few more lines of code, to read the file and and edit its content and write it back out.  That shouldn't matter, given all the benefits -- but there are libraries that cut out even that as well, for example the very handy [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny)

```
use Path::Tiny;

...

path($filename)->edit_lines( sub { s/#Port [0-9]+/Port $prt/ } );
```

I take it that `$filename` and `$prt` have been introduced earlier in the program.

There is also a `edit` method, which slurps the whole file.

Answer (score 1):

`system("sed ....")` is invoking a shell to parse the command line, which means that everything needs to be properly escaped according to the rules of the shell. This together with string escaping inside Perl makes it hard to get right. A much simpler way is to skip the shell and call `sed` directly and also use string concatenation to add the `$prt` at the right place (and don't forget to also include the "Port" string itself since you want to have it in the output):

```
 system('sed','-i','s/#Port [0-9]+/Port ' . $prt . '/', 'sshd_config');
```

Alternatively one could do it in Perl directly, i.e. something like this:

```
 open(my $fh,'<','sshd_config') or die $!;
 my @lines = map { s/#Port \d+/Port $prt/ } <$fh>;
 open($fh,'>','sshd_config') or die $!;
 print $fh @lines;
 close($fh);
```

This is a bit longer but does not rely on starting an external program and is thus faster. And if there is more to do than a simple replacement it is also more flexible.